# Not inserting into MySQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql

Following code for inserting data to the database table **pointoinvoice** but not inserting.

Please show me whats the error here;

```
String sql4= "INSERT INTO pointoinvoice (InvoiceDate, Company, ItemName, Qty, Price, PONo, GoodsRecieved ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    pst2=conn.prepareStatement(sql4);


    int noofdrugs=0;
    while(rs2.next()){

    String item= rs2.getString("ItemName");
    String qty=rs2.getString("Qty");
    String price = rs2.getString("Price");

    String sup=rs2.getString("Company");    

       pst2.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
       pst2.setString(2,sup );
       pst2.setString(3, item);
       pst2.setString(4,qty );
       pst2.setString(5,price );
       pst2.setString(6, pno);
       pst2.setString(7, no);
       pst2.addBatch();
       noofdrugs++;

    }

    pst2.executeBatch();
```

Comment: we don't even know what rs2 is, how you got it, if you even make it inside while loop

Comment: Since this is a single command, you should use `pst2.execute()` instead of `pst2.executeBatch()`

Comment: do you get any error while inserting

Answer (score 0):

try to commit the transaction using

```
conn.commit();
conn.close();
```

You should also focus on proper exception handling.